# set GCP for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to understand how FCM collect user data.
I know that FCM need to store some data (like deviceID) in order to send, for example, notification to a specific device.
My question is: **where, in the world, these datas are stored?**
Can I set a GCP location for this Firebase service? Or is inherited from GCP location settings in 'project settings' ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some services in GCP and Firebase are global, that is the case of FCM.

You can find information related to location storage in other Firebase services through this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0&hl=en

Notice there is no information about FCM because Google does not provide it and you should not be affected by it.

If you are worried about GDPR and personal information, do not be, no user provided information is stored there.